# How to filter out results based on a date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query result with two columns, The second column is the date in epoch unix time. The query takes a date parameter for example '7/1/2017'

What I want to do is choose the `leaseCode` that is most recent to the date entered. So in the sample below the first result `EDMGW | 1533013200000` would be closer to "7/1/2017" than the second result.

I do not want the second `EDMGW | 1690779600000` row in the result.
Any ideas you SQL gurus?

```
LseCode      | ExpDate  
-------------+---------------  
EDMGW        | 1533013200000  
EDMGW        | 1690779600000  
CHA08LL      | 1496210400000  
FRE05LL      | 1559282400000
```

Comment: closer to `7/1/2017`..does it mean the date can also be before `7/1/2017`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gordon's answer may be sufficient for your needs, and if so then go with it.  If you really want a query which will find the entry closest to a given date for each lease code, then we must do more work.  One approach is to convert the expiration date from milliseconds since the epoch into a SQL Server date, and then calculate the absolute difference in seconds between another date parameter which you choose (e.g. `2017-07-01`).

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LseCode
            ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(S, DATEADD(S, [ExpDate]/1000, '1970-01-01'), '20170701'))) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by lsecode order by expdate asc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

For your case, I am guessing that you really mean the earliest `ExpDate`.

Answer (score 0):

```
DEFINE @param DATE = '07/01/2017';

SELECT TOP 1 leasecode 
FROM t WHERE convert(date,dbo.ToDateTime(ExpDate)) <= convert(date,@param)
ORDER BY t.date DESC;
```

by most recent do you mean the first record with a date on or before the user provided date, or closest as in absolute difference to the date? Also, since you're using DAY, how do you want to deal lease codes on the same day - ties? Sry Can't test the date conditions, not before a machine at the moment.

```
/* one row only - with arbitrary resolution of ties absolute dstance */
WITH d AS (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
    ABS( datediff(day, CONVERT( date, dbo.ToDateTime(ExpDate) ) , convert( date, @param ) ) AS dst FROM t
)
SELECT * FROM d WHERE dst = 1;

/* all rows that with and ExpDate the same number of absolute days from your parameter */
WITH d AS (
    SELECT *,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY 
    ABS( datediff(day, CONVERT( date, dbo.ToDateTime(ExpDate) ) , convert( @param , date ) ) ) AS dst FROM t
)
SELECT * FROM d WHERE dst = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you meant that the closest date should be *on or after* 2017-07-01, you can use `top` along with some `dateadd` logic to convert the epoch to `date` for getting the date difference and using it to `order` the results.

```
select top 1 with ties lseCode,expDate
from t
where datediff(day,'2017-07-01',dateadd(second, expDate/1000, '1970-01-01')) >= 0
order by datediff(day,'2017-07-01',dateadd(second, expDate/1000, '1970-01-01'))
```